# Realm query not working with list

Tags: swift3, realm, realm-list

I have two Realm objects Location and Sector. that are defined in the following way:

```
class Location: Object {

  dynamic var id = ""
  dynamic var cityarea = ""
  let sectors = List<Sector>()

  override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
  }
}

class Sector: Object {
  dynamic var sector = ""
}
```

I am trying to create a query of sectors within a location using the following method

```
let location = uiRealm.objects(Location.self).filter("cityarea = '\(valCity)'").first
sectors = location?.sectors.sorted(byKeyPath: "sector", ascending: true)
print("sectors: \(sectors)")
print("location \(location)")
```

If I do this in the print statement I can see that I have the correct location. However sectors is returning ALL sectors, including those in other locations.

any thoughts?

Comment: Hmm, that code looks correct, so I'm wondering if it's an issue with the way your data has been saved. Can you please open your Realm file in the Realm Browser and post a screenshot of one of your `Location` objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All a bit strange. I closed down Xcode, re-opened, all worked well...